# Including CSS in my plugin shows up in source but does not apply to my elements

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm including a .css file in my plugin and the files show up on my page and I can see the path and click through the path to see the raw .css content. However, It is not applying to my HTML elements.

I removed the wp_enqueue_style() that included my CSS file in my plugin and placed the code in my theme's custom CSS template I'm using (just the raw css) and refresh and that works; the CSS is applied to my HTML elements as expected.

One thing to note is that in the same plugin I'm returning HTML that I want this CSS to be applying to through a shortcode on a page.

Is it something with the CSS not being registered/applied in time to pick up or find the elements if it's adding from a plugin? I need the CSS to be added from the plugin and not from the theme's template. Is there something I'm missing?
Thanks!

Comment: CSS is always active. It's not like Javascript where the elements have to exist first to act on them. Without code to peruse, my guess is that the pathname for the CSS file you're using with `wp_enqueue_style()` is incorrect.

Comment: Even though I can navigate to the raw css file through the view source? I also have js being adding in the same plugin and that works fine. I added them both basically the same way and nearly same path (other than js/css directories).

Comment: Just a guess. Without code to look at, there are to many possibilities.

Comment: Could you add in comment link to the page?

Comment: Thanks for you time. I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my own problem.

My plugin code was:

```
wp_enqueue_style('nbfx-fs-css', plugins_url('/assets/css/nbfx-fs.css', __FILE__), array(), null, true);
```

I took a look at my HTML source and found this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='nbfx-fs-css-css'  href='MY-CORRECT-CSS-FILE-PATH' type='text/css' media='1' />
```

And I noticed the **media='1'**. So apparently I need to leave the 4th parameter blank or provide 'all'.

I hope this helps someone else who copy and paste the wp_enqueue_style() function with set parameters from someone else.